# Swift - Model from Core Data release and exc bad access

Tags: ios, swift, memory, automatic-ref-counting, nszombie

I have EXC_BAD_ACCESS at this line:

```
self.accountControl.baseInfo = base
```

When I enabled NSZombies I get this error:

> -[CFString release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1478cbc0

I found out that my problem is here:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if baseInfo == nil {
        baseInfo = StorageManager.sharedInstance.getBaseInfo()
        reloadBaseInfo(false)
    }
```

Method `getBaseInfo()` in StorageManager:

```
func getBaseInfo() -> BaseInfo? {
    if let baseInfoCD = getBaseInfoCD() {
        var baseInfo = BaseInfo()
        baseInfo.update(baseInfoCD)
        return baseInfo
    }
    return nil
}

func getBaseInfoCD() -> BaseInfoCD? {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "BaseInfoCD")

    var error: NSError?
    if let fetchResults = managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error) as? [BaseInfoCD] {
        if fetchResults.count > 0 {
            return fetchResults.last!
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

I think that problem is with Core Data and it release object but I don't know what I am doing wrong. Here is screen from Zombie Instruments:
[image: Instruments screenshot]

What I am doing wrong? How can I fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really weird but I fix this by renaming property. My BaseInfo class has property:

```
var newTicket: String = ""
```

and BaseInfoCD has:

```
 @NSManaged var newTicket: String?
```

and there was a problem. I guess it's because it starts with new. When I rename it to ticketNew it works fine.